# Open File Dialog in VBScript Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line, vbscript, dialog, command-prompt

I want to show a **File Dialog** from *VBScript*, and I'd like to use *PowerShell*.

How can I use this *PowerShell* code with `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec()` to get the PowerShell output with the `StdOut` property?

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = "C:\"
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "|*.*"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
$OpenFileDialog.filename
```

Comment: If you're already writing in VBScript, why do you want to open the OpenFileDialog through PowerShell? Why not open it through VBScript?

Comment: CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog") is for XP, and CreateObject("MSComDlg.CommonDialog") is not on Windows 8, which is what I need. If I'm mistaken or you know of another way, please do tell. Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I did it. Haven't seen this method anywhere before.

I'm scripting for Windows 8, and other methods are not available, or elegant.

```
Function OpenFileDialog(sDir, sFilter, sTitle)
    With Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        If .FileExists("OUTPUT") Then .DeleteFile("OUTPUT")

        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run _
            "powershell.exe -command ""& {"& _
                "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms') | Out-Null;"& _
                "$o = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;"& _
                "$o.InitialDirectory = '"& sDir &"';"& _
                "$o.Filter = '"& sFilter &"';"& _
                "$o.Title = '"& sTitle &"';"& _
                "$o.ShowDialog() | Out-Null;"& _
                "$o.filename > OUTPUT"& _
            "}""",0

        Do
            WScript.Sleep 100
        Loop While Not .FileExists("OUTPUT")

        With .OpenTextFile("OUTPUT", 1, False, -1)
            Do While .AtEndOfStream
                WScript.Sleep 100
            Loop
            OpenFileDialog = .ReadLine
        End With

        .DeleteFile("OUTPUT")

    End With
End Function    

msgbox(OpenFileDialog("D:\", "|*.*", ""))
```